# when i edit span the range filter updates itself

Tags: javascript

I am just trying to make range filter can be changeable not by dragging the filter, but by typing the value. The value its self updates in console.log, but visually doesn`t just stays on one place (and then I have a problem to take value by $_POST method.

```
  <input id="range_filter" class="range-slider__range sum" type="range" value="10000" min="5000" max="100000" oninput="editor.value = range_filter.value">  
 <span contenteditable="true" id="editor" class="range-slider__value">0</span>
```

```
function edit() {
    //console.log("input event fired");
    var val1 = document.getElementById("range_filter").value;
    document.getElementById('editor').value = document.getElementById('editor').innerHTML;
    var val2 = document.getElementById("editor").value;
    
    
    val1 = val2;
    console.log(val1);
    console.log(val2);
}
var el = document.getElementById("editor");

if(el)
{
    el.addEventListener('input', edit, false);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d63sgacn/12/

Comment: `val1 = val2` won't magically update the value of the range slider, it just reassigns the variable.

Answer (score 0):

When you set `val` to `document.getElementById(...).value`, then `val` is not a reference to the element's value anymore - it's just a number stored in a variable, the same as if you had written `let x = 5`.

Instead of extracting the value, just keep references to the elements.

```js
function edit() {
  const slider = document.getElementById("range_filter");
  const numberInput = document.getElementById("editor");

  slider.value = numberInput.value;
}

var el = document.getElementById("editor");

if (el) {
  el.addEventListener('input', edit, false);
}
```

Also, there's no reason for the input to be a `<span>`. That doesn't limit user input to numbers only. Just make it a standard `<input type="number">`.

```html
<input id="range_filter" class="range-slider__range sum" type="range" value="10000" min="5000" max="100000" oninput="editor.value = range_filter.value">  
 <input type="number" id="editor" class="range-slider__value" value="0" />
```